# Does Pokemon: GO indicate that you've powered up a Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

One factor that's involved in guessing the IV's of a Pokemon is whether or not you have powered it up. This is apparently due to the fact that it takes two power-ups to raise your Pokemon one level, but wild Pokemon never half a "half" level.

Just looking at my list, I don't always remember if I have leveled some of my Pokemon up yet. While the difference doesn't appear to be significant, it would be useful to know.

Is there any indicator in the UI that you have powered up a given Pokemon before? (I checked the journal and didn't see anything there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. You just have to try and keep track of it yourself. Looking at the number of candy you have might help though. You could also "favorite" every Pokémon you power up to help keep track. See the following pictures, the Bulbasaur hasn't been powered up, but the Squirtle has.

[image: Squirtle with 0 candy] [image: Bulbasaur with 3 candy]

Comment: Where does this show that Squirtle was powered up, as opposed to being caught at a higher level?

Comment: there are 0 Squirtle candies... it doesnt "show" it, but it "implies" it since those 3 candies went somewhere. If I only have 1 squirtle that's pretty convincing, but if I have 100 pidgeys and 50 candy, not so much :)

Comment: @Studoku: I *think* it's an implication because you have a Squirtle and 0 candy, so you must have powered it up. But... long-time players won't be able to really judge things based on candy.

Comment: @Studoku it doesn't. That is the point. But as Mike said, the candies implies that you may have powered it up. Also, I happen to know that I powered up that Squirtle and haven't powered the Bulbasaur.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered renaming your Pokémon after leveling them up? You could, for instance, simply add a "+" to the Pokemon's name to keep track.